# Is it possible to reference enums in a GWT UiBinder context

Tags: java, gwt, enums, uibinder

I have an enumeration that looks like the following

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B;
}
```

And then I have a UiBinder file with a custom component that has a setter and getter expecting the enum above. (I've stripped the extra code for

```
<ui:UiBinder ....>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        ....
        <myNamespace:myComponent myAttribute="" />
        ....
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Can I reference my enum and put that value into myAttribute in any way? What I want to accomplish is something like this

```
<ui:UiBinder ....>
    <ui:with field="myEnumField" type="com.example.MyEnum" />
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        ....
        <myNamespace:myComponent myAttribute="{myEnumField.A}" />
        ....
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

However it would seem that I cannot do this with ui:with. Can I do this in any way at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You should be able to pass the enum to the attribute directly like,

```
<ui:UiBinder ....>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        ....
        <myNamespace:myComponent myAttribute="A" />
        ....
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

The MyComponent widget should have a uiConstructor that accepts MyEnum type.

```
@UiConstructor
public MyComponent(MyEnum myAttribute){
}
```

Answer (score 8):

After searching a bit more I realized that you could actually do the following:

```
<ui:import field="com.example.MyEnum.*" />
<g:HTMLPanel>
    ...
    <myNamespace:myComponent myAttribute="{A}" />
    ...
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: I like this better as you will get contextual highlighting/bug underlining in Eclipse, and you'll get autocomplete with the Enum types for that property. This way you'll discover problems earlier and you won't be depending on string literals (which encourages bugs).

Comment: I also like this better and am using this as my preferred method for referencing enums nowadays, but I felt that it was bad practice to mark my own answer as the accepted one. :)

Comment: Are you sure about this syntax ? It doesn't work for me in 2.4